# How can I run a TomoChain fullnode with pruned chaindata

Tags: blockchain, tomochain

I am running TomoChain node with `tmn`. Now, I would like to use pruned chaindata to save my storage.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the step below:

- Download the latest snapshot
- Replace current chaindata with the snapshot downloaded

Refer to link: https://docs.tomochain.com/masternode/snapshot/